# Pass a List<SomeObject> paramter to NUnit Test

Tags: c#, nunit, nunit-3.0

I am working on a NUnit test that needs to be able to accept a List as a parameter, and I am wondering how can I pass that list as a parameter?

I can pass in each user individually to the unit test like so:

```
[Test, TestCaseSource("GetUsers")]        
public void MyExample_Test(User user)
{   
    Asset.Pass();
}

private static List<User>GetUsers()
{
    List<User>users=new List<User>();
    users.Add(new User());
    users.Add(new User());
    users.Add(new User());
    users.Add(new User());

    return users;
}
```

But I need to pass in `List<User>` as WHOLE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of `TestCaseSource` is to return a collection where each object in the collection creates a new Test from your test method. You want to pass in a collection, so you need to wrap that collection in a collection. Talk about recursive :)

You want something like,

```
[Test, TestCaseSource("GetUserLists")]        
public void MyExample_Test(IList<User> users)
{   
    Asset.Pass();
}

private static IEnumerbale<List<User>> GetUserLists()
{
    IList<User> users = new List<User>();
    users.Add(new User());
    users.Add(new User());
    users.Add(new User());
    users.Add(new User());

    return new [] { users };
}
```

Normally, you will want to add multiple collections to the collection you are returning otherwise you don't need `TestCaseSource`, you would just construct your collection in your test method.

Comment: In terms of parameterized tests, what if I wanted to pass a collection via the TestCase() attribute, how would I do that? Right now I can pass basic types like Enum, Int, String, etc, and now it looks like this without dynamically generated collection: [TestCase(PersonType.Soldier, "John", 40, UnitTestNumber.Three)] but I guess I want it to look like this: [TestCase(PersonType.Soldier, "John", 40, SpecificAttributeCollectionForThisTest, UnitTestNumber.Three)]   SpecificAttributeCollectionForThisTest - would be a list of values just for this test.

Comment: You can't pass complex objects or collections because attribute parameters must be const